# Showing an exception while adding product to admin panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: "mfg_date"

> **models.py**
>
> from django.db import models
>
> ```
> '#Create your models here.<br/>
> class Product(models.Model):<br/>
>     prod_id = models.AutoField<br/>
>     prod_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)<br/>
>     prod_des = models.CharField(max_length=100)<br/>
>     mfg_date = models.DateField()<br/>
> ```
>
> **admin.py**

```
 from django.contrib import admin<br/> from .models import Product<br/>
 Register your models here.<br/> admin.site.register(Product)<br/>
```

> **views.py**

```
> from django.contrib import admin from django.urls import path from .
> import views
> 
> urlpatterns = [<br/>
>     path('index/',views.index,name='shopindex'),<br/>
>     path('aboutus/',views.aboutus,name='aboutus'),<br/>
>     path('contactus/',views.contactus,name='contactus'),<br/>
>     path('search/',views.search,name='search'),<br/>
>     path('productview/',views.productview,name='productview'),<br/>
>     path('tracker/',views.tracker,name='tracking'),<br/>
>     path('checkout/',views.checkout,name='checkout')<br/> ]<br/>
```

z

> Image of error

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gizYi.png)

> admin panel

[admin panel image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qt0f.png)

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is working now. The problem was **null=True** wasn't enabled.

Answer (score 0):

from the error image, what i understood is,

you are calling **pro_date**, instead of **mfg_date** somewhere in your views,

change that to **mfg_date**

Comment: That is about i had changed **mfg_date** to **pro_date** but after i'd seen it doesn't working i've changed it back to **mfg_date**.

Answer (score 0):

nothing wrong with your code . probably you forgot to apply migrations so run command

**python manage.py makemigrations** after that run **python manage.py migrate** .i think this will solve your problem